# Which keyboard shortcuts are the best to save time and improve productivity?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, shortcut

Other than cut, copy, paste, etc. which keyboard shortcuts do you frequently use that save time and improve productivity?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the handy shortcuts that I use:

1. **Command + M**: Minimizes the current/top application window into the dock
2. **Command + Space**: Shows spotlight
3. **Command + Option + D**: Hides/shows the dock
4. **Command + Shift + T**: Opens your last closed tab when you are in a browser
5. **Command + Shift + 3**: Takes a full-screen screenshot, then saves picture to desktop (add Control if you want to copy to clipboard)
6. **Shift+Command+Q**: Logs out of current mac account